# How to get Boolean values from request.POST dict

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I am using django 1.4 and I received parameters in `request.POST.dict()` which contain all values into Unicode format. Such as

```
{u'sam_status': u'true', u'address_type': u'false', u'is_deleted': u'false', u'title': u'true'}
```

But these values should be Boolean as they rendered from radio buttons from HTML page.

I want to convert this `request.POST.dict()` into a simple python dict which will have pythonic values such as for `'true'/'false' ==> True/False.`

Note: I don't want apply for loop because this may impact the performance as this works on huge data.

Comment: Is that an actual print of your request.POST dictionary? If the radio button wasn't checked, normally it's key wouldn't come back in POST at all.

Comment: @PeteTinkler I think that is for checkboxes, that is unchecked checkbox inputs do not send anything but for radio buttons it is a different thing.

Comment: There are radio buttons in html form and from Jquery i am firing an ajax call with serializing the form.

Comment: How could a for loop through a dictionary affect performance greater than the impact of sending that dictionary over HTTP in the first place?

Comment: Because I designed generic REST API which works all most more than 50 html forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How would django know that these questions are radio button input? It's all the same for Django because other form input answers are all sent in text format.

The right way to transform these values to right data types is through Django forms. You create a form for the answers you would like and when it is "clean"ed, it will be in right format. Check out [Django's own forms documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/).

You should have something like:

```
   form = MyForm(request.POST)
   if form.is_valid():
         status = form.cleaned_data['sam_status']
```

Note that django form in the background will do what you have said, it will basically go through data and normalize them according to form definitions. But even when the form is very big, it shouldn't cause much of a performance trouble. If it is very slow, I advise you to check other code you have for performance bottlenecks.

Comment: You are right but I am not writing django forms, I designed django API and getting this request from third party web application. So i can't use the above you explained. I am getting parameters in request.POST and just want to replace all its values into pythonic values.

Comment: But can't you do `import django.forms`? Since you have `request.POST` I'm assuming you have access to django. Otherwise you'll have to do all the normalization/form processing yourself and code the validation   and processing Django has provided for free.

Comment: No,because I designed REST API where we are dealing with Django model  ,But i got a hint from your answer that i'll try to create model form instance at run time and than i will fire is_valid method. i hope this would help me. What do you say??

Comment: I was thinking to use django.forms.models.modelform_factory to have generic model form instance but unfortunately this feature is available for Django 1.5+ and i am using 1.4 :(

Comment: @CrazyGeek I think ModelForm existed in 1.4 as well: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/ Also it shouldn't be too hard to code manually forms.

Comment: I was looking into the same doc but this  "django.forms.models.modelform_factory" is not in 1.4

Comment: `factory` is an internal class used by Django. It might have changed with new version but the functionality is there. Just create a form class, add Meta with model = YourModel and check if it is working right.

Comment: I just tried to import "from django.forms.models import modelform_factory" in my project shell having Django version 1.4.5 and it works.

Answer (score 7):

Having read the comments, the way you're doing it (not using Django forms, accepting POST requests from third party web apps and chosing to serialise the inputs as `u"true"` and `u"false"`) you have no option but to loop over the `POST` dictionary keys and convert the strings to bools manually in python. If this is really that much of a performance impact then it may be time to rethink your approach.

Out of curiousity, who is designing the forms that you're accepting and serialising? Are you even doing the serialising or are they? And what are you doing in terms of security? "generic REST API model form submission" and "third party web apps" sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Edit: Please don't use `eval()` to convert `u"False"` into `False`

```
>>> for key, value in request.POST.items():
...     if value == u'true':
...         a[key] = True
...     if value == u'false':
...         a[key] = False
```

Comment: Ok, So what approach you suggest to apply for loop and how ?

Comment: Depends on how you've serialised the form, but for your OP example, see edit

Comment: This works but if I have dict inside dict? I need a loop for all possibles dict's in my POST?

Answer (score 1):

This way you have a dictionary with possible values, while json should have smaller case 'true' and 'false'. This dict covers all the scenarios.

```
bool_dict = {'true': True, 'false': False, 'True': True, 'False': False}
bool_value = bool_dict.get(request.POST.get('bool_value', 'false'), False)
```

Once you do this, you are actually matching the value from `POST` request and getting bool type value from the dict. While you also provide a default value if `bool_value` in `POST` doesn't exist.
This sort of parses your values.

If you want to handle the situation where the value is not present maybe some try catch will help where it throws error is key is not present.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you encode your data in JSON when you post it? Like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url:url,
  type:"POST",
  data:data,
  contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType:"json",
  success: function(){
    ...
  }
});
```

Then, if you decode the response body in Django, everything will be fine:

```
requestPost = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: don't work for me. Django 2.1. `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`